# How to keep responsiveness while expanding div background height in CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem of rendering on my webpage, with the following code :

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 panel panel-default">
            <h1 class="dontmiss">Ne manquez pas l'ouverture !</h1>
                <p class="description">
                Indiquez votre adresse email <br>
                et obtenez un <span class="voucher">bon de réduction de 5%</span> valable un mois sur l'ensemble de la boutique.
                </p>
                <p class="description">  
                Nous vous contacterons le jour de l'ouverture :)
                </p>
                <form class="margin-base-vertical">
                    <p class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Entrez ici votre email" />
                    </p>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p class="text-center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn-warning submit"></button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div><!-- //main content -->
    </div><!-- //row -->
   </div><!--//container -->
```

CSS

```
.panel {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            margin-top: 2%;
            margin-right: 5%;
            margin-left: 5%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }

        .dontmiss {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        margin-bottom:3%;
        margin-top: 4%;
        }

        .description{
        font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 90%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 6%;
        }

        .voucher{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1em;
        color:#FB6E06;
        font-weight: bold;
        }

        .input-group{
        width: 100%;
        }

        .submit{
        margin-bottom: 5%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        width:50%;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
```

The .panel background stops right under the .input-group without taking into account my button.
I tried to apply a height in % to my .panel while adding an absolute height value to my .row, but in that case I lose the responsiveness (proportionnal expansion of contents) when I increase the screen size.

The question is how to have my div with white background to include my submit button without losing responsiveness.

Last info : I'm using twitter bootstrap V3.

Comment: Hey, i posted something, check if it helps.

Comment: Hey @Mattos ! Thnaks a lot, your code did the trick ! Good tip the form-group class, I use it now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood you.

### Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/luckmattos/xfHAq/1/

In bootstrap3 you need to use class `form-groups`, also you should avoid using classes like `col-md-X`and `panel` in the same element. Panel is basically a container so I create another div with this class and close after your submit button.

I made it without using `@media`queries to change the size of the button, set the button with 100% width and use classes `col-sm-6 col-xs-12` to set its size, together with `offset` classes to center the button. For that to work I create it a `row` as well.

It seems confusing, but check the form structure:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" placeholder="Entrez ici votre email" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
                <button type="submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn-warning submit">Envoyer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

You can also use `btn-block` class, that makes your button with 100% width at all screen sizes.

There are other ways to accomplished that, let me know if this help.

Thank you.